# Getting Date and Time of Location(Timezone)

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, location

I need date and time on action by user.

But getting device date/time will not workout because we can manually adjust our device date/time.

We can do API for that.

But I think there will be some open source API to get Date/Time by location or any other go.
Please direct me. Thank You

**TimeZone Conversion**

```
try
    {
String ourDate = "2018-10-17T06:36-04:00";
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        Date value = formatter.parse(ourDate);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, MMM,dd,yyyy'Z'hh:mm aa");
        dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        ourDate = dateFormatter.format(value);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ourDate = "00, 000,00,0000'Z'00:00 00";
    }
    return ourDate;
```

Comment: You can try with this `LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
long time = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime();`

Answer (score 0):

please check this API to get the current time

http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now

to change it to current user locale you can use 
(Kotlin code)

```
 SimpleDateFormat("date_time_poattern", Locale("user_locale")).format(time_in_millisecond)
```

change date_time_poattern to your own pattern, change user_locale to your user locale and finally add the time in millisecond

Comment: time_in_millisecond is the one we get from above api(currentDateTime)?

Comment: you need to convert this currentDateTime to millisecond

Comment: @Mohammed Rbabah - conversion to local TimeZone from EST is not working in lollipop. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project:

https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android

You must initialize the library on a background thread:

```
TrueTime.build().initialize();
```

After that, you can call

```
TrueTime.now();
```